# Trouble using XPath

Tags: c#, xpath

I am trying to parse the Spotify lookup register, but after several attempts I am trying here as a last resort.

Related XML:
http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=http://open.spotify.com/track/3aKJVWH2QOsaMtiCLxYHZX

Related code:

```
var response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
xml.LoadXml(response);
var name = xml.SelectSingleNode("//track/name").InnerText;
var artist = xml.SelectSingleNode("//track/artist/name").InnerText;
var album = xml.SelectSingleNode("//track/album/name").InnerText;
var length = xml.SelectSingleNode("//track/length").InnerText;
```

Related debugging: http://screencast.com/t/yDc8f7Wyzv9P

Comment: I've debugged the actual xml contents so I know for a fact they exist.

Comment: None, except the variables remain null, because it can simply not find the element by the path.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you should prefix your XPath expression, or ommit the default namespace :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx#Y1372

states :

Note
If the XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed that the namespace URI is the empty namespace. If your XML includes a default namespace, you must still add a prefix and namespace URI to the XmlNamespaceManager; otherwise, you will not get a node selected. For more information, see Select Nodes Using XPath Navigation.

following your example :

```
 XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
 nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1");
 var name = xml.SelectSingleNode("//ns:track/ns:name", nsmgr);
```

Comment: Now, I've already tried that but I gave it another shot anyway, and it didn't turn out well: [link](http://pastebin.com/K8MPJBWm)

Comment: you should still add the namespace (second phrase) and use the nampespace in the xpath (3th phrase)

Comment: Yes, I guess we're down to wrong Xpaths? http://screencast.com/t/yDc8f7Wyzv9P -- as you can see the values are there, with or without the namespacemanager

Comment: I have to go, I'll try to come back here tomorow, success

Comment: +1: Fixed up sample to use namespace prefix for each level (ns:name)

Answer (score 1):

**This is a FAQ**: You need to register the namespace an use it in the XPath expression

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1");
var name = xml.SelectSingleNode("/ns:track/ns:name", nsmgr);
```

Also note that there is no need for a starting `//` operator when th schema is well known.

Comment: @miceiken: Your [code example](http://pastebin.com/34zv5av4) has a wrong namespace URI. Read my answer carrefully.

Answer (score 0):

Quoth [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectsinglenode.aspx):

> If the XPath expression does not include a prefix, it is assumed that the namespace URI is the empty namespace. If your XML includes a default namespace, you must still add a prefix and namespace URI to the XmlNamespaceManager; otherwise, you will not get any nodes selected.

The XML document does have a default namespace, specifically `http://www.spotify.com/ns/music/1`. You'll need to supply a prefix and namespace URI for your xpath query.

Comment: Thanks, but look at my comment above, it didn't seem to work, here's an attempt at adding the namespace: [link](http://pastebin.com/dB0iGyGJ), I think there might be something wrong with my XPaths tho

Comment: @miceiken: You cannot use the empty namespace for xpath, see [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.addnamespace.aspx). You'll have to specify a prefix in the `AddNamespace` call, and then use that prefix in your xpath expression (e.g. `//ns:track/ns:name`).

Comment: Now, I did try that also. I just find it so weird seeing that the values really are there http://screencast.com/t/yDc8f7Wyzv9P

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and make your life easier?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to try another approach, thanks to Windcape I found XmlSerializer

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Track));
var track = (Track)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader);

var time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(track.length);

var ircResponse = string.Format("{0} - {1} ({2}) | {3}min {4}sec | {5}% popular",
  track.artist.name,
  track.name,
  track.album.name,
  time.TotalMinutes, time.Seconds,
  Math.Round(track.popularity * 100, 0));

CommandHandler.Msg(chan, ircResponse);
```

Comment: This "solution" is a lot more inefficient than just selecting the necessary nodes -- as it performs full analysis of the complete XML document and in addition constructs a complete new object out of it. Orders of magnitude more work !